# ContentObserver new onChange public API crash on android 10 (api 29)

Tags: android, contentobserver

In ContentObserver, there is a new public API overload "onChange(boolean, Uri, int)" that delivers a int flags argument. in android 10 (api 29) only, if i call super.onChange(selfChange, uri, flags) app crashed with this error

```
Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No super method onChange(ZLandroid/net/Uri;I)V in class Landroid/database/ContentObserver;
 or its super classes (declaration of 'android.database.ContentObserver' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

so i added this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
     super.onChange(selfChange, uri, flags)
}
```

and solved my problem
of course flags value for pre api 30 is always 0
i have many questions
why there is no @TargetApi for this method or any warning?
am i doing something wrong at all?
how should developer know this method "super.onChange(selfChange, uri, flags)" is not work on pre api 30 and crash on api 29?

Comment: Developer reads the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver#onChange(boolean,%20java.util.Collection%3Candroid.net.Uri%3E,%20int)

Comment: @blackapps Only this part of the doc can be useful: "To ensure correct operation on older versions of the framework that did not provide richer arguments, applications should implement all overloads." but does not mention calling super class in Android 10 cause crash

Comment: It tells you that the method is added at 33. That should be enough for you.

Comment: @blackapps Yeah but calling super of this method crash just on Android 10 otherwise lower Android or upper is working fine /:
I have 2k crashes of this method only for Android 10 users :D